# Masking of DEM in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, masking

I have a clipped DEM of my study area in ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 which I want to use for SWAT project set-up, but I need to mask it.

How do I go about it?

I'm new to the use of ArcGIS.

I don't want to use the extract by mask option.

Comment: Does this Q&A help?  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150103/deleting-polygon-defined-area-from-raster-layer-in-arcgis-for-desktop It sounds to me like it may be the same as what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear why you don't want to use the extract by mask option.

The only other way I know of is to set the mask through the environment settings:

[ArcGIS Help 10.1 - Mask (Environment setting)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w0000001t000000).

Comment: I don't want to use extract by mak because I want the mask to be a little bit bigger than the study area.

Comment: In that case I would first buffer the study area layer and then use the result of that as a mask.