# Calculating Zonal Statistics outside of polygon using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, zonal-statistics

Is there a way to calculate zonal statistics outside of polygon?

I want to extract the mean values outside of the polygon. In this case, instead of calculating for the land, I want to use the ocean.

I use ArcMap 10.5 for my analysis.

Comment: Simply blank raster inside polygon https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150103/deleting-polygon-defined-area-from-raster-layer-in-arcgis-for-desktop/150179#150179 and see statistics of result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an "ocean" polygon to use for Zonal Statistics. Create a polygon from the boundaries of your entire raster, and then clip out the land, leaving only ocean behind.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but maybe you could use the Select tool for selecting your shp file. Then use the **Zonal Statistics as Table tool** which will get the mean value from the database using the selected polygon in raster format to define the zone. The resulting table with a single record in it will be used to store and pass the desired values back to the database. Finally, the table will be deleted and the next polygon will be selected to repeat the process.

You may check this link, they have done something similar.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220479365_Geoprocessing_Solutions_Developed_While_Calculating_the_Mean_Human_Footprint_for_Federal_and_State_Protected_Areas_at_the_Continent_Scale