# Deleting polygon defined area from multi band raster layer in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, landsat-8

This is a similar question to [Deleting polygon defined area from raster layer in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150103), but I need the answer to be able to apply to multi bands since I am working with a RGB file.  I have a Landsat 8 file and have used SAGA to classify the clouds (wasn't to fond with ArcMaps).  I  I want to use arcmap to remove the polygon clouds from my original landsat image (SAGA is too slow and crashes constantly).  From the post linked above, I have converted the shape file to a raster.

I was thinking may changing all the cloud raster values to zero (not sure how to do this) and then multiplying with the original landsat 8 raster.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Created/had a shapefile of the area proposed
2. Erased the Cloud/Shadow polygons with the above shapefile
3. Clipped the RGB raster with the new erased shapefile

[image]

[image]

Comment: Glad you found a solution yourself ;)

Comment: Thank you and thank you for posting as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do that, with the **Basic** license:

1. Import yout RGB image in your mxd.
2. Convert your cloud polygons (shapefile format, no need to have a arster here) to **graphics**.

[image]

3. Make sure the graphic is/are selected using the selection tool in the Draw toolbar and right click your RGB raster layer in the Table Of Contents and choose Data -> Export Data

[image]
[image]

4. Export with the Extent parameter set to Selected Graphics (Clipping) and the option **Clip inside flagged** (this does the magic)

[image]

[image]

Comment: For some reason the "convert features to graphics" is grayed out for me.  The file is actually a `.sprm.shp`.  Not sure if that matters?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realize you were converting the raster file.  I actually just solved the problem.  I will post my answer below and try yours out.

Comment: No, in step 2 I said to ceonvert the Shapefile to Graphics, and in step 4 use this graphic to clip your RGB image.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  Okay I changed my `.sprm` to a shapefile in SAGA.  I copied your steps above, however now the "Selected Graphics (Clipping)" in step 3 is grayed out.  Does my RGB need to be in a specific format.  Mine is a 32 bit floating point.

Comment: interestingly, it seems that if you don't have your graphic selected, ArcMap won't recognize that you can use it to clip the raster. I'll update my answer to reflect this, gimme one sec please...

Comment: Step 3 updated!

Comment: I am still working on yours, cause there is never one way to find a solution, though it is taking a bit to process because I think I have so many polygons . That I am selecting (almost 20,000).

Comment: Yes, this works.  Unfortunately because I have so many polygons that I am selecting, the answer I posted above is easier to process.