# ArcGIS Raster Calculator Erase raster from raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-calculator

Two rasters

1. slope (black and white grid with slope values)
2. rasterized property (red, values do not matter)

I want to erase the red raster from the slope raster
[image]

I found this thread

https://community.esri.com/thread/190381-how-to-perform-reverse-clip

and they suggested something like this (for my case block is the red raster and buff is the slope)

```
Con(IsNull("block.tif"),"buff.tif")
```

this produces the output in the multi colors. But it is not the full erase, part of the buff/slope is missing

I do not want to go the vector conversion route.

Answer needs to use Raster Calculator syntax

[image]

Comment: Set extent to Union of inputs and repeat.

Comment: @FelixIP i am not sure what you mean

Comment: Environment extent.

Comment: See comments to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150103/deleting-polygon-defined-area-from-raster-layer-in-arcgis-desktop/150179#150179  you need extent equal one of grey thing.

Comment: @FelixIP `Con(IsNull("block.tif"), "buff.tif")` where block is the red I am trying to erase from the buff

Comment: I am getting the same result as my 2nd picture

Comment: Perhaps compute red using grey extent first

Comment: @FelixIP I see what you mean now, you're suggesting worked. Write it in an answer and I will accept. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Reclassify](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) tool to turn your red areas into [NoData](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/nodata-in-raster-datasets.htm) values and the red area NoData values to  zeros. Before you do this ensure use the [geoprocessing settings](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/setting-geoprocessing-environment.htm) to ensure the output from the **Reclassify has the same extent at both data sets**.  Then add the resulting reclassified surface with your slope using the [Plus tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/plus.htm).

```
Con(IsNull("block.tif"), "buff.tif")
```

Comment: need this in raster calculator

Comment: @ziggy  Why are you restricted to only using the raster calculator?  If you are using the raster calculator you also have access to Modelbuilder and the Spatial Analyst toolbox.  But in any case, you can turn your NoData values to 0 with Con(IsNull(raster), 0, raster).  You can also use SetNull in the raster calculator to generate the NoData values but that expression would depend on the values in your red area.  See here;  lhttp://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/setting-cell-values-to-nodata-with-setnull.htm.

Comment: I am actually doing this whole process in PostGIS but not as many people answer the PostGIS raster questions so I am getting the raster calculator syntax down in ArcGIS 1st and then will apply it to PostGIS

Comment: as for this `Con(IsNull(raster), 0, raster)` I am getting the exact same results I posted in the 2nd pic of the question

Comment: Both raster values in this con function are pointing to the same 'red raster' ?  This function Con(IsNull(raster), 0, raster) is looking at the red raster, converting any NoData values to 0, and leaving any data values in there original state. If that is not the case maybe you have chosen a symbology that is not showing all the data in the 'red raster'.

Comment: I am not trying to delete the red raster out of the black/white grid

Comment: Sorry, I am unclear what your question is then because you state on line three 'I want to erase the red raster from the slope raster'.

Comment: yes correct, so i want the slope raster with NO red raster covering it

Comment: add the raster calculator syntax to your answer and I will accept