# Failing to use the correct Con expression in raster calculator in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, con

So, I am trying to use the `Con` statement in ArcMap to add a certain value to a raster dataset (raster2) if the data is the same as an other dataset (raster1), if not I should just stay the same. I tried to use the expression:

```
Con(("raster1" == 1), ("raster2" + 1.5), "raster2")
```

But it seemed to null out any values that where not within raster 1, and therefore loses a lot of values and data.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Your word problem and conditional expression do not correlate. I would have expected `raster2` in the first term.

Comment: See my comments to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344569/arcgis-raster-calculator-erase-raster-from-raster?noredirect=1#comment562895_344569

Comment: The issue here are different extents. So, set extent to r2. In calculator type r1. Use original expression, replacing r1 by r3. r3 is output of first calculation.

Answer (score 0):

If Con is your only operation - you could try using the standalone Con tool ([see documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm)).

You could try:

```
Con ('raster2', ('raster2'+'raster1'), 'raster2',('raster2'=='raster1'))
```

Comment: This is not an issue he is talking about. BTW his expression is correct.

Comment: good point @FelixIP, I missed that this was in raster calculator, and now suggest the Con tool