# Exclude some part from raster using mask

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a raster and I want to remove only small portion of that raster by using mask and then remaining raster without that portion should be my final raster. Searching for something like erase tool.

Comment: Have you checked [Extract By Mask](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-mask.htm)?

Comment: @ahmadhanb Extract by mask will extract the masked portion. But I want to remove the masked portion and the remaining part of raster should be left behind.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150103/deleting-polygon-defined-area-from-raster-layer-in-arcgis-desktop/150179#150179

Comment: @FelixIP Thank you