# Raster file TIFF not integer to integer to polygon

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro

I am using a raster file .tif and converting it to integer and then to a polygon layer - all so that I can use the clip analysis tool. Are there problems to make these conversions (am I corrupting the original raster grid?) or should I be doing it in another way? At the end of the day I need to clip some of the raster areas with another polygon layer.

Comment: Is this post helpful: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/how-do-i-load-a-pitemx-file/m-p/705169#M31160

Comment: Use Con(~IsNull( pgonRaster), sourceRaster) similarly to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150103/deleting-polygon-defined-area-from-raster-layer-in-arcgis-desktop/150179#150179

Comment: You can convert the polygon to a 1/noata raster and mask with that.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest solution I know so far that works in ArcGIS, not sure about Pro:

- zoom to your polygon and select it
- Go to Windows - Image Analysys and select your raster
- Use Clip tool - left most in a picture below

[image]

Use floppy disk icon (last one) to save clipped raster if necessary.