# Erase function in ArcGIS for raster

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, erase

Is there a tool similar to the Erase tool but for rasters?

I have a raster and a shapefile, and I am trying to use the shapefile to erase the overlaying area from the raster, similar to this:

[image]

Comment: You can't remove center pixels from a raster, only mask them to NODATA.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150103/deleting-polygon-defined-area-from-raster-layer-in-arcgis-desktop#150179

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Extract by Mask](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.0/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-by-mask.htm) will do this as @Vince suggested but with some tweaks you need to ensure.

Here is an input example, I want to erase everything under the the blue polygon:

[image: Data]

Ensure Extraction Area is set to OUTSIDE then under the environment settings make sure you set:

- Processing extent to the input raster
- Cell size to the input raster
- Snap Raster to the input raster

With those correctly set the result is:

[image: Erased]